# How to create a anonymous function to loop through an array, passing parameters and returning strings?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I have the follow array of queries:

```
<?php

$queries_0 = [
                /*
                  Custom Info
                */                
                0=>"INSERT INTO tbl1(field1, field2,field3,created_at) VALUES ('$p[0]', '$p[2]', '$p[2]', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');",
                1=>"SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
                    FROM ((Orders
                    INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
                    INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID)
                    WHERE
                    Shippers.ShipperName='$p[0]'",


                /*
                  Payments
                */
                2=>"SELECT * FROM Customers
                    WHERE City LIKE '$p[0]%';",
                3=>"SELECT * FROM Customers
                    WHERE Country='$p[0]' AND City='$p[1]';",

];
```

The goal is to get a desired query only passing its key and necessary parameters.

To achieve that goal this is what I did:

```
$queries = array( 
  0=>function(array $p) {
    return "INSERT INTO tbl1(field1, field2,field3,created_at) VALUES ('$p[0]', '$p[2]', '$p[2]', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');";
  },

  1=>function(array $p) {
    return "SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Shippers.ShipperName
                    FROM ((Orders
                    INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID)
                    INNER JOIN Shippers ON Orders.ShipperID = Shippers.ShipperID)
                    WHERE
                    Shippers.ShipperName='$p[0]'";
  },

  2=>function(array $p) {
    return "SELECT * FROM Customers
                    WHERE City LIKE '$p[0]%';";
  },

  3=>function(array $p) {
    return "SELECT * FROM Customers
                    WHERE Country='$p[0]' AND City='$p[1]';";
  }
);
```

Test:

```
$sql=$queries[0](['f1','f2','f3']);
echo $sql;
$sql=$queries[3](['US','NewYork']);
echo $sql;
```

Results:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1(field1, field2,field3,created_at) VALUES ('f1', 'f3', 'f3', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP');    
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Country='US' AND City='NewYork';
```

Now I would like to clean up that array **queries** to make it like **$queries_0**. The goal here is to avoid repetition of function, since we are doing the same -  creating a anonyomous functions and passing parameters $p and returning the string.

This is my attempt so far, without anonymous functions, and it is not working:

```
function get_sql(array $param) {
    foreach ($param as $k => $p) {
        return $queries_0[$k];//$queries_0[$k] is the string itsef.
    }
}


$res=get_sql(["0"=>['f1','f2','f3']]);
echo $res; //null
```

what should be the approach with or without anonymous functions?

Comment: `$res` is `null` because `$queries_0` is not in the `get_sql` function scope. Set your error reporting to `E_ALL`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use PDO and parameter binding. For example, by using positional "?" placeholders...

```
$queries_0 = [
    'INSERT INTO tbl1(field1, field2,field3,created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)',
    // and so on
];

$pdo->prepare($queries_0[0])->execute(['f1','f2','f3']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree in using PDO parameter binding.
But if you want to use your own library.
Here is my solution.

```
    function getSQL(array $params){
    $opts = array(
                    '0'=>'SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE username=?'
                   ,'1'=>'INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(?,?,?,?)'
                   ,'2'=>'UPDATE tbl SET username=? WHERE id=?'
                   ,'3'=>'DELETE FROM tbl WHERE id=?'
                ); //queries

    foreach($params as $param => $sub){
        if(!is_array($sub) && !($sub===null))return null; // invalid -- value not array or null
        $query = $opts[$param];
        if(substr_count($query,'?') != sizeof($sub))return null; // invalid -- not equal number of params
        $last_position = strpos($query,'?');
        foreach($sub as $value){
            $query = substr_replace($query,$value,strpos($query,'?',$last_position),sizeof($query));
            $last_position += strlen($value)+1;
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
echo getSQL(['0'=>['0']]).'<br/>';              // SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE username=0
echo getSQL(['1'=>['0','gello?','gel?g?g?g','3']]).'<br/>'; // INSERT INTO tbl VALUES(0,gello?,gel?g?g?g,3)
```